# Why does the error say: class has no attribute in my case

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

I have the following code. I'm running a "fit" function and I'm getting the following error: 'P' object has no attribute 'iterations'. I do not really understand why its happening, I declare it in the "init" method.

```
import numpy as np

class P:
    def __init__(self, iterations: int = 100):
        self.w = None
        self.iterations = iterations
        self.classes_map = None
        
    def fit(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> NoReturn:
        X = np.hstack((np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X))
        self.w = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
        classes = np.unique(y)
        self.classes_map = {-1: classes[0], 1: classes[1]}
        y_ = np.where(y == classes[0], -1, 1)

        for _ in range(self.iterations):
            predictions = np.sign(X.dot(self.w))
            incorrect_indices = predictions != y_
            if np.any(incorrect_indices):
                self.w += np.dot(y_[incorrect_indices], X[incorrect_indices])

    def predict(self, X: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        X = np.hstack((np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X))
        predictions = np.sign(X.dot(self.w))
        predictions[predictions == -1] = self.classes_map[-1]
        predictions[predictions == 1] = self.classes_map[1]
        return predictions
```

So I try to call it:

```
X, true_labels = make_blobs(400, 2, centers=[[0, 0], [2.5, 2.5]])
c = P()
c.fit(X, true_labels) #AttributeError: 'P' object has no attribute 'iterations'
```

Comment: provide the make_blobs method and its dependencies for local testing pls

Comment: This is the method from the scikit-learn library. It generates isotropic Gaussian blobs for clustering. Here is the [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html) to the documentation